# how can we know that we have released memory

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have created a game of two levels.Now when we are in level one i create sprite sheet for animation and a lot of sprites.On reaching a certain score i move to level 2 now here here is another sprite sheet and a lot of variables.

When i am  moving from level 1 to level 2  using.

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[Level2 node]];

when i lose on level 2 i move back to level 1 using

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene:[Level1 node]];

What happens to the sprite sheet and other sprites i created before on level 1 ? If i retry level 1 will the sprite sheet and sprites i created before be removed automatically ?or they will exists in this new scene?

kindly clear me these issue i am having a lot of trouble because of no understanding of this..

thank you in advance..   :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cocos2d almost everything is marked as autorelease.  So when you create a new scene it is not released because it becomes the main scene.  Once it is no longer the main scene, if you do not specifically retain it then it will be released.

In the case you state above I believe that both scenes are retained as you are using the director like a stack, pushing the scenes on each other.  If you never need to go back to level 1 you can use CCDirector's `replaceScene:` method instead to release level 1.

Having a custom pause scene or bonus round might be a good example of when to use the `pushScene:` call.